# How to resolve this issue "Could not create access key for user amplify-trial:"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

[image: This is the error I receive on creating the user]

This is the error I receive on creating the user. I followed the tutorial on getting started page of AWS amplify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since , i have an aws educate account.

IAM: You can create users, but cannot attach a login profile. You are not permitted to use SAML or third party providers with IAM. **You cannot create access keys for additional users.**